# Texture mapping Not correct

Tags: texturing, uv

I've just baked all my textures into one as I'm planning to use this in unity, however when I tried to use the baked texture the model looks messed up, the UV project fits as seen here:

[image: screenshot showing UV map]

I've got a simple node setup here just an image texture however even if I use the UV map for the other model the texture does not line up.

[image: material nodes]

I'm not sure if I'm being stupid so I've attached the blend file and the baked texture and any help would be appreciated.

[image: texture file]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you click the little camera next to the UV map name?  Loading the texture looks like this:

[image]

...but when I select the "new" UV set, it works fine:

[image]

is that what your question was?